# объединение элементов массива keras timeseriesgenerator multiple output

Tags: массивы

tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator на вход принимает
элементы массива series, строки:

```
series = array([[0.30090289, 0.26909887, 0.4839495 , 0.29760977],
                [0.2772557 , 0.24773788, 0.40919748, 0.30150688],
                [0.25483693, 0.23997025, 0.41009919, 0.30644323],
                [0.26828819, 0.31574598, 0.50513977, 0.32969602],
                [0.28204656, 0.32000165, 0.51875564, 0.3421668 ],
                [0.27799275, 0.3133909 , 0.50009017, 0.34970122]])
```

Каким способом возможно объединить элементы массива по n строк. Например при n =2:

```
target = array ([[[0.30090289, 0.26909887, 0.4839495 , 0.29760977],
                  [0.2772557 , 0.24773788, 0.40919748, 0.30150688]], 
                 [[0.2772557 , 0.24773788, 0.40919748, 0.30150688],
                  [0.25483693, 0.23997025, 0.41009919, 0.30644323]], 
                     ..................]
```